# How to sort Map<String, Set<String>> by another Set size

Tags: java, sorting

I have a map

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map
```

I'd like to write a function that returns a list `List<String>` which sorts map by size of set of the value of each key. The item in the list should be the keys of the map. What's the best way to do this?

I know I can use set.size() but how do i keep the relation of size of a set to corresponding key string?

Comment: To what does a single entry in the desired output list correspond?

Comment: This is about implementing a sort algorithm or using java collections utilities to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it this way using Stream API:

```
List<String> sortedKeys = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.getValue().size(), b.getValue().size()))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Frostbit answer is pretty right but you could use comparingByValue() instead:

```
List<String> sortedKeys = map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.comparingByValue(a.size(),b.size())) //getValue() removed
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```